# Java: com.sun.tools.javac.Main not found when trying to compile Hadoop program

Tags: java, hadoop

When I try to compile my program in Hadoop with this command

```
bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCounter.java
```

from Hadoop folder, it says

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

I looked in similar threads where people suggested to check if `JAVA_HOME` is properly stated. So in `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`I added this line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

then checked if `tools.pack` is properly unpacked in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib` and it was. Then I tried `javac -version` which gave

```
javac 1.7.0_65
```

I tried to reinstall Java but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why would the `tools.jar` be unpacked instead of simply added to the classpath? What's your classpath?

Comment: tools.pack, sorry for confusion

Comment: echo $CLASSPATH gives nothing, i tried export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/java/tools.jar but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: What is `tools.pack`?

Comment: Duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260900/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-sun-tools-javac-main-hadoop-mapreduce

Answer (score 17):

Try to set *HADOOP_CLASSPATH* environment variable

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Comment: This worked for me.  It isn't very well documented in the setup of hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you don't use a JDK to start Hadoop. The main difference between the JRE (pure runtime) and the JDK is the Java compiler `javac`. To see if you have a Java compiler, you need to check two places: There should be a `javac` in the `$JAVA_HOME/bin` folder plus there must be a file `$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`.

In your case, the first one (the binary to start the compiler) can be missing but you absolutely need the `tools.jar`.

You say that you have a `tools.pack` but I haven't heard about this one before. Use your package manager to search for `openjdk` and then look for a package in the result list which says `jdk`. On my system, that would be `openjdk-7-jdk`. Install this package and the error should go away.

Comment: tools.jar exists as well as javac

Comment: also there is openjdk-7-jdk installed when i searched

Comment: In that case, your setting is getting ignored. If `bin/hadoop` is a script, then try `bash -x bin/hadoop ...` to see which commands are executed and what variables are set. To redirect the output to a file, use `|& tee hadoop.log`. You can then search for `hadoop-env.sh` and `JAVA_HOME` in `hadoop.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade Hadoop to 2.9.2 and it's working.

I also had these in my environment:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```