# Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to learn MapReduce but I am a little lost right now.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Usage

Particularly this set of instructions:

```
Compile WordCount.java and create a jar:

$ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
```

When I type in `hadoop` in my terminal I am able to see the "Help" made which provides arguments so I believe I have hadoop installed.

When I type in the command:

Compile WordCount.java and create a jar:

`hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java`

I get the error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main`

I know I have Java installed and working on my computer because I've used it before to create other programs.

This command outputs:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Maybe I am missing a set of Java tools? Not sure

Comment: is your Wordcount.java is in bin/hadoop directory.

Comment: are you able run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: com.sun.tools.javac.Main not found when trying to compile Hadoop program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299273/java-com-sun-tools-javac-main-not-found-when-trying-to-compile-hadoop-program)

Answer (score 20):

I got same error.

And i solved it by add HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment parameter:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
```

Please make sure that you installed OpenJDK7. I am using Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: As it is originally stated in documentation (tutorial): https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

The `bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java` is finaly running as
`java com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java`.

If your classpath/javahome is right, then try to type `java ...` yourself, and check the name `com.sun.tools...` by using TAB key. Maybe the name is not a proper one. (egg. you are using java from Oracle rather than SUN)

Another suggestion is modifying the `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`. Add the `tools.jar` into `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 2):

You may not install jdk. Check your /lib/tools.jar in your java folder. 
If not, **#sudo apt-get install default-jdk** and the error disappears.