# Hadoop WordCount error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am following the documentation found at this link

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Usage

When i try to compile for WordCount.java and create a jar, I get the following error

```
bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

I have verified my $JAVA_HOME and $HADOOP_CLASSPATH in the hadoop-env.sh file and also verified to see if I have the jdk

Here are the contents from `hadoop-env.sh`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/"
.......
.........
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
  if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"
  else
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
  fi
```

I am not sure the reason behind error or if I am missing another key configuration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260900/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-sun-tools-javac-main-hadoop-mapreduce

Comment: @shmosel i did come across that, but still no luck with the error

Comment: @cricket_007 just following the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense in that loop... Nor does checking the existence of the variable first

```
if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"
else
```

You need to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"`, as the documentation says for that class to be found. And that class is only available in the JDK

But, you could just run `javac` command to compile code. Not sure why the docs have you calling that class.

[How to compile a Hadoop program](https://janzhou.org/2014/how-to-compile-hadoop.html)

> ```
> $ javac -classpath ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH} -d WordCount/ WordCount.java
> ```
>
> To create jar:
>
> ```
> $ jar -cvf WordCount.jar -C WordCount/ .
> ```
>
> To run:
>
> ```
> $ hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount input/ output
> ```

**Suggestion** Please use Maven/Gradle to create proper JAR files, and an IDE to write code.

<sub>P.S. Not many people actually write plain MapReduce</sub>